# Extracting file name without number from the end

Tags: python

How do extract file name from with numbers on both end?

I have extracted file name 56flybox007 using :

`filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), 56flybox007)`

Results in `flybox` but I want to remove numbers from prefix part so result be like: `56flybox`

Comment: You mean you want to remove from suffix then, right?

Comment: I want to keep the numeric from suffix but not from prefix

Comment: thats not what your post suggests. Your post says the result should be `56flybox` that is that you want to keep the prefix digits 56 and drop the suffix digits 007

Answer (score 1):

Try Using this code:

```
import string

Sample = "56flybox00"
cleaned = Sample.rstrip(string.digits)
print(cleaned)
```

Output:

```
56flybox
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex here, even if there are a lot of other ways to achieve this, regex are powerful and could be easily modified if your needs change:

```
import re

rx = re.search(r'(\d*\D+)\d*', '123abc456')
print(rx.group(1))   # >>> '123abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    file = "56flybox007"
    file[:file.find(filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), file))]+filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rstrip method of string to remove characters from the right hand side of the string. In this case you pass all the digits to rstrip and it will remove them from just the right hand side.

```
files = ["56flybox007", "45NotherFile456", "78LasstFile45"]
out_files = [file.rstrip("0123456789") for file in files]
print(files)
print(out_files)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['56flybox007', '45NotherFile456', '78LasstFile45']
['56flybox', '45NotherFile', '78LasstFile']
```